# Several Android apps in the same Gradle project

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I have a fairly typical Android-Studio/Gradle project with several library modules and one module that defines the launcher activity. So, one APK, so far so good.

But I want to have a second APK generated out of a new top-level project. Note that it's not just a *flavor*, it's a different app that needs to be in a different module. Still I want to reuse most library modules, so I want it to be in the same Gradle project (and the same Git repo).

Can I just create a new Android module (`apply plugin: 'android'`) with its own launcher activity? In that case, what will `./gradlew assemble` build?

Comment: Maybe it will be usefull for you - it is possible to include gradle module in several "projects". If in root directory you have `projectA` (with `moduleA` inside) and `projectB`, add to projectB's `settings.gradle`:

`include ':moduleA'`
`project(':moduleA').projectDir = new File('../projectA/moduleA')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I just create a new Android module (apply plugin: 'android') with its own launcher activity? In that case, what will ./gradlew assemble build?

Yes you can create a new Android module and when you run `./gradlew assemble` it will build both modules.

In case you want to build just one you can run `./gradlew :module:assemble`